# How do I make combo boxes reflect loaded data?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I'm having issues with ComboBoxes. I've learned how to make an item selected write a certain amount, but I don't know how to have the combo box reflect an item within it when I load data.

When I load the data, the ComboBox reflects the data in the file as opposed to an item tied to the ComboBox.

How might I go about having the ComboBox reflect that?

The following code is what I use to load the data.

```
Private Sub Readfile()
    Try
        Dim Reader As New PackageIO.Reader(FilePath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
        Reader.Position = 78414
        Item1 = Reader.Position
        ComboBox1.Text = Reader.ReadInt32

        Reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The following code is what I use for it to write the correct data. What could I do to have it show "Item 1" in the combo box instead of "19" upon loading the source file?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged


    If ComboBox1.Text = "Item 1" Then
        Try
            Dim Writer As New PackageIO.Writer(FilePath, PackageIO.Endian.Big)
            Writer.Position = 78414
            Writer.WriteInt32(19)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ErrorToString)
        End Try
    End If
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow you. What is the problem? What do you mean by "reflect an item"?

Comment: When I load the file, I want it to show the item that would be tied to that number.

Item 1 has a numeric value of "19" but when I load the file, it shows "19" in the combo box and not "Item 1".

Comment: How do you populate the ComboBox? By a datasource? If so, a DataTable? If not, how?

Comment: I just added items into it. There's no datasource or datatable. I couldn't find any tutorials that explained how to do them very well.

Comment: @ProjectTira Including the codes used to load data from file to combobox will be helpful. That allow us to give more specific suggestion. From currently provided info, I can only suggest to set DisplayMember property of the combobox properly..

Comment: I've added the loading code to the original post.

Comment: When I click on the "DisplayMember" setting, it's empty.